# how to install selenium in Odoo?

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I work on Odoo and I want to automate a task in Odoo using selenium then I install it and I make my script and updating the module I have an error: import selenium
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'
I installed selenium and I also import it into the classroom.

I'm confused I don't know what to do at this point

Answer (score 0):

Frederic Dipama

Try to hit this command :

```
sudo -H pip3 install -U selenium
```